# Basic conditional Awk one-liner

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

Trying get `awk` to look into a file and check if a column has a value.

- If it has a value of "x" then print "x" into an email (via `"| mail -s "`).
- If it does not match "x" then print "no value" but still send mail.

Trying something along the lines of:-

```
awk -F ''{if($3 != 0) {a = ($3); print $0, a;} else if ($3==0) print "No updates"}'  file.in | mail...etc
```

Comment: What can the input look like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
awk '$3 == "x" { print $3 } $3 != "x" { print "no value" }' file.in | mail ...
```

or

```
awk '{ print ($3 == "x" ? $3 : "no value") }' file.in | mail ...
```

or

```
awk '$3 != "x" { $3 = "no value" } { print $3 }' file.in | mail ...
```

Given the file

```
1 2 3
2 3 x
4 5 x
```

the three `awk` programs will produce the output

```
no value
x
x
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
awk '{ print ($3!="x")?"No Updates":$3 }' infile | mail ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried by below method

```
g=`awk '{print NF}' l.txt| sort -nr | head -1`
```

For x pattern exsists

```
for ((l=1;l<=$g;l++)); do awk -v l="$l" '$l == "x" {print "exists in"l"column"}' l.txt| sort -u; done |mail ..
```

for x pattern doesnt exists

```
for ((l=1;l<=$g;l++)); do awk -v l="$l" '$l != "x" {print " doesnt exists in"l"column"}' l.txt|sort -u; done| mail
```

input file

```
[root@praveen_2 ~]# cat l.txt
10 x x
10 x x
```